# SAML Authentication - Cordova Hybrid Mobile application using in app browser

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, saml, saml-2.0, hybrid-mobile-app

We are trying to integrate the SAML authentication in mobile apps(HybridCordova+angular JS)

I have tried below approach,
Approach :
Step 1: Mobile application open InAppBrowser -> Load the SP url -> Automatically SP URL redirects to IDP(any). to show the login page.(window.open("url"))
Step 2: Once login successful in IDP, Inappbrowser should dismiss and back to mobile app.

To achieve the Step 2, I have tried to used "LoadStart","LoadStop" listeners. But it dismiss the browser before login gets successful.

Any idea? How to achieve this?

```
$scope.opensaml = function(){
        appBrowser =  window.open("https://example.com/login”, '_blank', 'location=no,closebuttoncaption=Back to App');
        appBrowser.addEventListener('loadstart', function (event) {
            console.log("Load Start",event.url)
        });
        appBrowser.addEventListener('loadstop', function (event) {
           console.log("Load Stop",event.url);
           appBrowser.close();
        });
        appBrowser.addEventListener('loaderror', function (event) {
            console.log("Load Error",event.url)

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> loadstop: event fires when the InAppBrowser finishes loading a URL.

You are closing the InAppBrowser as soon as it's done loading your page.
You should use instead

> message: event fires when the InAppBrowser receives a message posted from the page loaded inside the InAppBrowser Webview.

That is of course conditional to the fact that you can trigger a message event on your login page.

Comment: Message event is not firing in mobile application(iOS,Android and Windows).  we are using the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser - 4.1.0 version "appBrowser.addEventListener('message',  function (event) {
            console.log("LOAD message ",event.url)
            alert("LOAD message");
        });"

Comment: Do you fire it from the window ?

Comment: Hi Eric, it works in android and iOS. But it does not fire in windows platform. Any alternative approach for windows? also to fire this event in iOS&Android, we need to run a script.(postMessage)

Comment: Well, maybe at least upvote my answer or yet even better, validate it and create a new question for the Windows side of thing.